# minio web console on a separate host

Tags: minio

Could you help me?  I installed a minio cluster on a VM with Centos 7, the cluster works, there is access to the minio web console (it works on these hosts), I specify it as a login / password MINIO_ROOT_USER/MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD. Now I want to install minio web console on a separate VM (Centos 7), I'm trying to do it using https://github.com/minio/console, but I can't figure out how to pass my login/password MINIO_ROOT_USER/MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD to connect to my cluster. I tried to create a new user through mc, as written in the instructions on https://github.com/minio/console - as a result, I connect with the new user through the current console, but it doesn’t work from the new console, authorization error.